# Disable touch screen in Android in accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, talkback, accessibility

I am developing an Android application for the deaf and blind using the accessibility service

Need to disable the touch screen, because android app is controlled through a third-party device

I tried to add a view to WindowManager and disable everything there (`FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`, `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE`), but as far as I understand, it disabled the touch screen only in this view, but not at all

I can request any type of permission except the root

**EDIT:**

Due to Android security, disabling the touchscreen is not possible without **root**, but you can use **Proximity Sensor** to disable touchscreen until first power button pressure

Comment: You can't disable the touch screen.  Things like the home button, back button, and other system UI elements will always stay usable.  You can disable touch on any view you own, but I don't think there's any way to turn it off for an entire app, much less for an outside app attached to an acessibility service.

Comment: You can't disable touch screen but you can lock the whole screen or sleeping mode

Comment: Probably if I can't to disable touch screen, I may to add some magic view like in Lock Screen app

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations and good will for you are working for a good cause.

Not sure exactly how to do this but One way is to create a full screen activity - hide navigation bar and soft navigation buttons also -- please refer [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive)

And 2. override onBackPressed and never allow it to call super.onBackPressed() or relaunch your app in OnPause() method.

Hope this helps somewhat.